# Is that the right way to set an id in Vue.js component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, phaser-framework

I am trying to integrate Phaser 3 with Vue.js 2.

My goal is to create a Vue.js component associated with a game canvas.

My initial solution was:

```
<template>
  <div :id="id">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Phaser from 'phaser'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      id: null,
      game: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.id = 'game' + this._uid
    var config = {
      parent: this.id,
      type: Phaser.CANVAS
    }
    this.game = new Phaser.Game(config)

    ....

  }
}
</script>
```

This code attach the game canvas to my template. But to my surprise it only worked 'sometimes'.

I figured out, after hours of debugging, that my div element in the DOM wasn't updated with the id when I was instantiating my new Game.

So I came up with the solution of instantiating the id in the beforeMount () method as follow:

```
<template>
  <div :id="id">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Phaser from 'phaser'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      id: null,
      game: null
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.id = 'game' + this._uid
  },
  mounted () {
    var config = {
      parent: this.id,
      type: Phaser.CANVAS
    }
    this.game = new Phaser.Game(config)

    ....

  }
}
</script>
```

It is working, but I would like to know if there is a more simple and elegant solution ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect your first example to work because it has invalid javascript. You can't set another a variable in an object's definition like you're trying to do. I'd think you could just set `this.id` in the `mounted` hook before initializing `var config`. But I also don't know where you're getting the `this._uid` value, so I also feel like there's code you haven't shared which might also be affecting the outcome.

Comment: I was also surprised, but it is valid. I forgot to mention that I am using Webpack to transpile this piece of code ....

Comment: mmm no, not valid. You maybe have your webpack configured or ide setup it a way that it's not showing that as an error (although I'd also be surprised if that's true), but it would not transpile to do what it looks like you're attempting. Another explanation would be that you didn't copy/paste the sections of your code to your post correctly, so what you're testing is different from what you've shared here.

Comment: This is the full unchanged code, and I can assure you it is working:
https://gist.github.com/stephane303/a6f52a0ea31728eef2dc882886e1b4e2

Comment: Your second example looks valid. I'm saying your first example has invalid javascript, which was surely messing things up. Your question is "how can I make my code simpler?" and I'm saying that you could probably just put `this.id = 'game' + this._uid` as the first line in your `mounted` hook without having to use `beforeMount`.

Comment: i get it now,  will try it, no so easy to communicate only in writing ....;-)

Comment: I made the fix in the question, but the problem remained the same, only the second solution is working .... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One better solution for integrating Phaser.Game into the application is directly passing the config the HTML element, [a configuration supported by Phaser.Game](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Game.html).

To get a reference to a HTML element in vue, you can use [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), these are basically id's, but local to the component itself, so there is not risk in creating conflicts.

```
<template>
  <div ref="myDiv">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Phaser from 'phaser'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      game: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    var config = {
      parent: this.$refs.myDiv,
      type: Phaser.CANVAS
    }
    this.game = new Phaser.Game(config)
    ....
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need multiple instance on the same page, could that be a problem ? I will try it, thank you .

Comment: With refs, that is not a problem, with id's, you need to have an unique id per component (and prevent conflicts between components accidentally using the same id)

Comment: Hence https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-uniq-ids should be usefull in that situation

Comment: I don't think it's good to work around a problem using an external package, if the framework itself has solutions already, but that's my opinion, feel free to add another answer to your question explaining how to do it using the external package you linked, and accept that if that helps you the most

Comment: Without the external package, I do not understand how to have a unique id in my page. The solution you are suggesting do not solve the unique id problem, or maybe there is something I do not understand.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve the id problem, because that is basically a symptom of the real problem as far as I see. I'm trying to solve the problem that `new Phaser.Game(` needs to render in the correct element, and this can either be done using unique id's, or directly passing a HTMLElement, and `this.$refs.myDiv` returns a html element for the referenced node. See the documentation for `Phaser.Game`, it says "string | HTMLElement"

Answer (score 0):

Vue3 sample:

```
<script setup>
import { ref,onMounted } from 'vue';
import Phaser from 'phaser'

const myDiv = ref(null)
let canvasWidth = 750;
let canvasHeight = 1450;

onMounted(() => {        
    const config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        parent: popWrap.value,
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };
    const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
})
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="myDiv">
  </div>
</template>
```